# Tic Tac Toe invincible AI code issue

Tags: c, recursion, pseudocode, tic-tac-toe, scoring

I have decided to make a C program of Tic-Tac-Toe.  I am trying to make the AI invincible at the moment but I have encountered a problem.

And I wrote this:

```
int getFutureScoreOfMove(char square[][columns], char turn)
{
      int row, column, curBestScore, score;

      if(turn == 'C')                         curBestScore = -100;       
      else                                     curBestScore = 100;        

      for(i = 0; i < 3; i ++)
      {
           for(j = 0; j < 3; j++)
           {
                if(square[i][j] == ' ')
                {
                        if(turn == 'C')      
                        {
                                 square[i][j] = 'X';
                                 score = getFutureScoreOfMove(board, 'U');     
                                 square[i][j] = ' ';
                        }
                        else                  
                        {
                                 square[i][j] = 'O';
                                 score = getFutureScoreOfMove(board, 'C');
                                 square[i][j] = ' ';
                        }
                        if(turn == 'C' && score > curBestScore)           curBestScore = score;
                        if(turn == 'U' && score < curBestScore)           curBestScore = score;
                }       
           } 
      }  
      return(curBestScore);                    
}
```

There is something wrong in the code, as it is NOT invincible AI, and is ineffective.  Why? And how can I fix it?

Thank you :)

Comment: Please don't destructively edit your questions, especially after people have taken the time to add answers. (If this question has no value - delete it.)

Comment: im sorry, i wont do it again, it wouldnt let me delete it

Answer (score 2):

`getFutureScoreOfMove` calls itself, but it never modifies `board` with the move you're checking. This means it finds the same move again, resulting in infinite recursion. When calculating the outcome, you need to fill in the move on the board before recursing.

Comment: Thank you.  I have corrected this by adding `board[row][column] = 'X';` before the recursive call, and hen reseting it after (see the edit), but it still is not invincible

Answer (score 1):

The pseudo-code just implements a min/max strategy without actually computing *anything* to do with tic-tac-toe.  Your code just recursively calls itself infinitely.

Comment: Thank you. I have corrected this by adding board[row][column] = 'X'; before the recursive call, and hen reseting it after (see the edit), but it still is not invincible